# How can I get profile picture (of friend)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get user's friends profile picture, but I want the picture to be in type large.

Let's say that I'm ok with `taggable_friends`  (a separated issue itself), so I get it like this:

Login + permissions:

```
    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];

    loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), (self.view.center.y - (loginView.frame.size.height / 2)));
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

Now the `taggable_friends` :

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=invitable_friends" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [[result objectForKey:@"invitable_friends"] objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"friend.name %@", friend.name);
        NSLog(@"friend.objectID %@", friend.objectID);

    }

}];
```

Ok, so I have the `objectID`, how can I use it to get the user's large profile picture?

This isn't work for me:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?type=large
```

Since the user ID is ~50 chars, and isn't 10-12 chars usually.

Any help please?!

Thanks in advance!